# Making My Child Programme fit my picture box

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

```
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1

Private Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal dwFlags As Integer, ByVal dx As Integer, ByVal dy As Integer, ByVal cButtons As Integer, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Integer)

<DllImport("user32.dll")> Public Shared Function SetParent(ByVal hwndChild As IntPtr, ByVal hwndNewParent As IntPtr) As Integer
End Function

Public Function wait(x As Integer)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(x)
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim Process1 As New Process
    Process1.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Runique.jar"
    Process1.Start()

    For x = 1 To 20
        wait(100)
        SetParent(Process1.MainWindowHandle, PictureBox1.Handle)

    Next
End Sub
```

When I run this my process1 is being created in the bottom-right corner of the Picture Box.
How do I make it fit my picture box? And how do I make it immovable?

Comment: After calling SetParent(), use the MoveWindow() API to set the location to 0, 0.

Comment: could you give me an example of how you would do that please I cant find the movewindow() method ?

Comment: It might be easier to use [SetWindowPos](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setwindowpos) with the "NOSIZE" option.